# How to exit from crontab -e?

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

I wanted to run my python program at startup for Raspberry Pi.

I followed youtube videos (ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zRXauWUumSI&t=8s) and accomplished the same by using the `crontab` command.

However, how do I exit from this command and come back to intial condition of Pi.

Comment: After you typed `crontab -e`, what did you see? `crontab -e` should have done 1 of two possible things: **1)** opened your crontab in the default editor (likely `pico`), or **2)** prompted you to choose a default editor (`pico` should have been a choice). What did you see?

Comment: Which editor do you get? If it's `EDITOR=nano crontab -e` then the command is `CTRL+X` and follow the prompt. If It's `EDITOR=vi crontab -e` the the command is `:wq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is not a Pi specific Question, and I didn't look at your video.)

The normal default system editor is `vim` (or some variant thereof).
Consult the man for `vim` for editor commands.

**However** if you aren't a vi user and don't want to memorise lots of arcane commands change the default system editor to one you are familiar with.
I use `nano` (I thought that Raspberry Pi OS already had this as default, but I may be mistaken).

Run one of the following

```
sudo select-editor

sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

and follow the onscreen prompts.